# Change location of an Azure IoTHub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I would like to change the location of my IoT Hub [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrvFD.png).
For some reason there doesn't seem to be any way to do it within the portal. Am I going to have to delete the IoT Hub and create it again?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to move an Azure resource to a different location. If you need to move your resource you will have to develop your own migration plan and redeploy the resource in the desired location.